# Getting problem related to webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have varchar value in database like (1110000111) when i search through autocomplete extender it display like (2013) means it converted into binary to decimal format but my requirements is it should display in (11100000111) this format means in original format.

so plz help me how can i achive this through webmethod one more think when i taking a value like (11111-00000-22222) that it display like (111100) that only

my code is ........

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]         //WebMethod for Search Asset Number

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchAssetNumber(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["connStringForAutoComplete"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT numAssetNo From AssetMaster where " +
            "numAssetNo like '%'+ @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> vcName = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    vcName.Add(sdr["numAssetNo"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return vcName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sdr["numAssetNo"] is coming back as an integer, you can use the optional base parameter in convert.tostring to specify base 2:

```
Convert.ToString ((int)sdr["numAssetNo"], 2)
```